# flutter how to get rid of a icon padding?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I did eveything solution on Stackoverflow

but it still has a space horizontally

I want to set these icons very closely each other

my code is this

```
     Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          MediaQuery.removePadding(
            context: context,
            removeLeft: true,
            removeRight: true,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                width: 30.0,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                    color: Color(0xff60B906),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xff60B906),
                  iconSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          MediaQuery.removePadding(
            context: context,
            removeLeft: true,
            removeRight: true,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                width: 30.0,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                    color: Color(0xff60B906),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xff60B906),
                  iconSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

any solution that difference to mine please?

[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ZQo.png)

and I want it to be very close

Comment: add images how do you want and how it is now

Comment: @KirillMatrosov I added it

Comment: You just want to remove the space between the arrow or outside the arrow?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha yes I want to remove the space between the arrow

Comment: That is not a padding... that is actual icon.. you can't remove them unless you stack them on top of each other

Comment: replace your `IconButton` with `Icon` because `IconButton` has default padding.

Comment: @Doc yes you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Stack` Widget

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
              onPressed: null,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                  color: Color(0xff60B906),
                ),
                color: Color(0xff60B906),
                iconSize: 30,
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 20,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                    color: Color(0xff60B906),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xff60B906),
                  iconSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: thank you for answering but it seems it has a space also. I want it to be very close like ">>" text

Comment: oh you are right I changed the value of a Positioned then it worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve this
[image: if you want to achieve this]

there are two options

1- download it as PNG image to your folder assets and make it a child
instead of row

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Image.asset(
            "imagePath",
color: Color(0xff60B906),
            height: 16,
            width: 16,
          ),
        ),
```

2- if you want it as Icon make it as Icon data from SVG from this site 
https://fluttericon.com/
and make it as usual

Answer (score 0):

Stack them on top of each other using a Stack, then wrap one of them in a padding with only left padding of the points you need to get it look the way you want.