# Flutter Web Icon doesn't fit inside Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have tried removing all padding and border and put the icon inside a FittedBox but the are still parts of the Container that are visible. How can I remove them? Thank you in advance.

[image: Orange Icon above a blue Container]

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Cupertino App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: Center(
          child: CupertinoButton(
            minSize: 15,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              width: 40,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.blue,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 0,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              child: const FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                child: Icon(
                  CupertinoIcons.minus_circle_fill,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container colors are visible because the `Icon` assets comes with default padding, You can check this question: [How to get rid of a icon padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61383770/10157127),

You can use `transparent` Color on the Container to hide it.

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
  color: Colors.transparent, // here
  border: Border.all(
```

Answer (score 1):

you can size

```
Icon(
CupertinoIcons.minus_circle_fill,
color: Colors.amber,
size:40
 )
```

and you dont need container border default is none

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.blue,
                //border: Border.all(
                  //width: 0,
                  //color: Colors.transparent,
                // ),
              ),
```

or here

```
CupertinoButton(
            minSize: 15,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              width: 40,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              decoration:const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.amber,
                
              ),
              child: const FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.remove,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  size:40
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```